# How to convert diagonals stored in an array back to a matrix?

Tags: python

There is a matrix, it can be of any size.

Below I use a test matrix.

```
arr1 = [ [1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15, 16],[17, 18, 19, 20],[21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

I select diagonals in it according to the method below, where each individual color is a kind of diagonal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy1aB.png)

I use this function to find:

```
def find_diag_values(mtrx):
n, m = len(mtrx), len(mtrx\[0\])
left_ans = \[\]
right_ans = \[\]
start_coords = \[(y, 0) for y in reversed(range(0, n, 2))\]
start_coords += \[(0, x) for x in range(1, m)\]

for s_y, s_x in start_coords:
    x = s_x
    left = []
    right = []
    for y in range(s_y, n, 2):
        if x >= m:
            break

        left.append(mtrx[y][x])
        left.append(mtrx[y + 1][x])

        right.append(mtrx[y][-(x + 1)])
        right.append(mtrx[y + 1][-(x + 1)])
        x += 1

    left_ans.append(left)
    right_ans.append(right)

return left_ans, right_ans`
```

And then I call her accordingly:

```
arr1 = [ [1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15, 16],[17, 18, 19, 20],[21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

```
vertical_diags_values = find_diag_values(arr1)horizontal_diags_values = find_diag_values(arr1)))
```

```
print("lft_rght", vertical_diags_values[0], "\n", sep="\n", end="")print("rght_lft", vertical_diags_values[1], "\n", sep="\n", end="")printing("top_btm", horizontal_diags_values[0], "\n", sep="\n", end="")
```

```
printing("btm_top", horizontal_diags_values[1], "\n", sep="\n", end="")`
```

Here is the result:

```
lft_rght[[17, 21], [9, 13, 18, 22], [1, 5, 10, 14, 19, 23], [2, 6, 11, 15, 20, 24], [3, 7, 12, 16], [4, 8]]
```

```
rght_lft[[20, 24], [12, 16, 19, 23], [4, 8, 11, 15, 18, 22], [3, 7, 10, 14, 17, 21], [2, 6, 9, 13], [1, 5]]
```

```
top_btm[[17, 21], [9, 13, 18, 22], [1, 5, 10, 14, 19, 23], [2, 6, 11, 15, 20, 24], [3, 7, 12, 16], [4, 8]]
```

```
btm_top[[20, 24], [12, 16, 19, 23], [4, 8, 11, 15, 18, 22], [3, 7, 10, 14, 17, 21], [2, 6, 9, 13], [1, 5]]`
```

Next, I work on the diagonals and get this result for one type of diagonals:

`lft_rght     [[0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 10, 14, 0, 0], [0, 0, 11, 15, 20, 0], [0, 0, 12, 0], [0, 0]]`

For each array of diagonals, the values may be different.

How do I convert an array of diagonals back to a matrix for each kind of diagonals?

To get a matrix of the original size with its own values.

Here is an example of how the reverse transformation should look.

```
arr2 = [ [0, 2, 0, 0],[0, 6, 0, 0],[0, 10, 11, 12],[1, 14, 15, 0],[0, 2, 0, 20],[0, 3, 0, 0]]
```